# Is it possible to have Gmail index more mail to allow searching of older messages?

Tags: gmail, gmail-search

Search operators using dates are very limited to only about a year.

Comment: Welcome to [webapps.se]. What do you mean by "to have Gmail index more mail"? Also, please show what you tried and add a brief description of your search efforts as is suggested in [ask].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always **customize your dates range** using the `after` and `before` [operators](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/7190) as in the example given

```
xda after:2019/1/19 before:2021/2/17
```

[image]

Comment: This is exactly what I was trying and it was only returning results less than a year old. If a date was "before" one year, it would return nothing. But it's working today, so it must have been a one-off.